# from sql server to pandas dataframe with pyodbc - while working with small tables, it gives an error on complex sql queries

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
1 step: Create a temporary table with pyodbc into sql server for objects
2 step: Select objects from temporary table and load it into pandas dataframe
3 step: print dataframe
```

for creating a temporary table i work with pyodbc cursor as it trohws errors with pandas.read_sql command. wheras it trohws an error if i try to convert the cursor into a pandas dataframe. even with the special line for handling tuples into dataframes.

my program to connect, create, read and print which works as long as the query stays simple as it is now. (my actual approach has a few hundred lines of sql query statement)

```
import codecs
import os
import io
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc as po

server = 'sql_server'
database = 'sql_database'

connection = po.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = connection.cursor()

query1 = """
CREATE TABLE #ttobject (object_nr varchar(6), change_date datetime)
INSERT INTO #ttobject (object_nr)
VALUES
('112211'),
('113311'),
('114411');
"""

query2 = """
SELECT *
FROM #ttobject

Drop table if exists #ttobject
"""


cursor.execute(query1)
df = pd.read_sql_query(query2, connection)
print(df)
```

Because of the lenght of the actually query i save you the trouble but instead post here the error code:

```
('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

This error gets thrown at query2 which is a multiple select statement with some joins and pivote functions

When I'm trying to put everything into one cursor i got issues with converting it from cursor to DataFrame (tried several methodes, maybe someone knows one which isn't on SO already or has a special title so i couldn't find it)

same problem if I'm trying to only use pd.read_sql then the creation of the temporary table is not working

I don't know where to go on from here.

Please let me know if i can assist you with further details which i may overwatched in accordance to my lostlyness :S

**23.5.19 Further investigating:**

- According to Gord i tried to add autocommit to true which will work
  for simple sql statements but not for my really long and
  timeconsuming one.
- Secondly i tried to add

  "cursor.execute('SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC schema.proc @muted = 1')
- At the moment i guess that the first query takes longer so python already starting with the second and therefore the connection is
  blocked. Or that the first query is returing some feedback so python
  thinks it is finished before it actually is.
- Added a time.sleep(100) after ececution of first query but still getting the hstmt is busy error. Wondering why this is becaus it should have had enough time to process the first
- Funfact: The query is running smoothly as long as I'm not trying to output any result from it

Comment: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/300

Comment: https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/issues/54#issuecomment-311371209

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d51d71e3-512f-4143-a8db-3e39286cb746/microsoftodbc-sql-server-driverconnection-is-busy-with-results-for-another-hstmt?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: Are you really doing a SELECT immediately followed by a DROP TABLE (of that same table) in the same anonymous code block?

Comment: @GordThompson yes i di somehow also for testing purpose. now im curios about your best practice ways and what the downside is of doing it in my poor unexperienced way?

Comment: Try adding `autocommit=True` as a kwarg to your `pyodbc.connect` statement and see if that helps any.

Comment: @GordThompson while adding the autocommit=True is working on the simple sql statement version it is not with the heavy load sql query. at the moment i guess that the first query takes to much time in place to finish before python is trying to start the second and therefore blocks the connection. could that be the case? Anyway isn't there any solution where i can just run the whole sql statement and get the result? Because the query itself is tested and works fine in dBeaver with 1 database but in this usecase i need to combine two